# Strange unexpected defrecord behavior: a bug or a feature?

Tags: clojure

```
;; Once upon a time I opened a REPL and wrote a protocol
;; definition:
(defprotocol SomeProtocol
  (f [this]))

;; And a record:
(defrecord SomeRecord []
  SomeProtocol
  (f [this]
    "I don't do a whole lot."))

;; And a very useful side-effect free function!
(defn some-function []
  (f (SomeRecord.)))

;; I call my function...
(some-function)
;; ...to see exactly what I expect:
;; user=> "I don't do a whole lot."

;; Unsatisfied with the result, I tweak my record a little bit:
(defrecord SomeRecord []
  SomeProtocol
  (f [this]
    "I do a hell of a lot!"))

(some-function)
;; user=> "I don't do a whole lot."
```

Looks like a bug to me. I just cannot be sure after having seen so
many false compiler bug reports in c++ user group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to re-define the `some-function` after redefining the record again. The reason for this is that `defrecord` creates a new type (using deftype) and using the `(SomeRecord.)` notation inside the function will bind the code to that type even after a new type with same name is defined. This is why it is usually prefer to use `(->SomeRecord)` notation to instantiate the record, using this notation will make your code work like you expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you elaborate what's the difference between `(SomeRecord.)` and `(->SomeRecord)`?

Comment: `(SomeRecord.)` is a reader macro translated to special form `(new SomeRecord)`. Since it is a special form it may not follow seemingly obvious rules, as in this case. I guess that `(new SomeRecord)` is translated to something internal, like `(new package.SomeRecord$some_unique_identifier)`. `(->SomeRecord)` OTOH is just a function which is defined by `(defrecord)`. When you redefine your record, it keeps the Clojure name but not the internal name, so constructor calls become obsolete, but the function is simply redefined with new meaning, so calls to it are still valid.